# Click on dynamically added UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was a stubborn WinForms protectionist for years, but I changed my mind and try to get in touch with WPF. I like it so far.

---

**My problem:**

I've created a UserControl "SelectableRectangle" which Contains a Rectangle. Well - in one of my application I create hundreds of them, programmatically/dynamically.

And I want to be able to "click" on them and use different tools, for example changing the color. Therefore I need to know in my main window on which exact SelectableRectangle I clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you really want to get into WPF you should first learn about MVVM and in your case DataTemplates. Then this question is going to be obsolete

Comment: Any good information about this topic you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if your usercontrol implements an event handler you can link an event-handler to an event like that:

```
 mycontrol1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(mycontrol_Click);
```

and then implement the method

```
 private void mycontrol(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // do things here
    }
```

Further, if your usercontrol is derived from either UIElement, UIElement3D or ContentElement you can use the AddHandler method:

```
mycontrol1.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(mycontrol_Click))
```